# Magento2 : Area code not set: Area code must be set before starting a session

Tags: magento2, setup-upgrade, magento-upgrade

- Old Version : **2.2.2**
- Upgraded Version : **2.2.4**

i'm getting error while run command `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

```
Module 'Magento_Store':
Module 'Magento_Directory':
Module 'Magento_Eav':
Module 'Magento_Theme':
Module 'Magento_Customer':
Upgrading data.. Area code not set: Area code must be set before starting a session.
```

I have tried with  `php bin/magento sampledata:reset` but still not solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
vendor\magento\module-customer\Setup\UpgradeData.php

public function __construct(
        ...
        ...
        \Magento\Framework\App\State $state,

    ) {
        ...
        ...
        $state->setAreaCode(\Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_GLOBAL);

        );
    }
```

**EDIT**
get idea from ss which file have to change http://prntscr.com/mmj3oe

Comment: This is not an answer. Would you care to explain what this code is supposed to do?

Comment: @ketan Did you found the answer?

Comment: get idea from ss which file have to change http://prntscr.com/mmj3oe